# Update com inner query selecionando a mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
UPDATE cp_feedback_trabalho as a SET
    a.visivel = 1
WHERE a.dhEnvio IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 
        b.id 
    FROM cp_feedback_trabalho as b 
        WHERE 
            b.id_pessoa_que_enviou = a.id_pessoa_que_recebeu AND 
            b.id_pessoa_que_recebeu = a.id_pessoa_que_enviou AND 
            b.id_projeto = a.id_projeto AND
            b.dhEnvio IS NOT NULL
)
```

Eu obtenho o seguinte erro ao executar:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause

O que pode estar errado?

Comment: O que você quer fazer? Pode escrever também o SQL(em português e não em SQL, só para entender), tipo o que você quer fazer, pois não estou entendo qual as relações.

Comment: Olá Fernando, eu quero apenas atualizar um campo (visivel) com base em outro registro que por acaso está na mesma tabela que será atualizada (cp_feedback_trabalho). O problema está nas variáveis (a e b)

Comment: Que eu saiba, no MySQL, não é possível fazer update numa tabela e usar a mesma como critério na cláusula `WHERE`. Uma sugestão seria usar uma tabela temporária com o resultado de um `SELECT` dessa mesma tabela com a cláusula `WHERE` do update (se possível é claro).

Answer (score 1):

Está um pouco desorganizado o seu SQL.

E o erro ali já está dando uma dica, "você não está especificando a tabela de target, onde você vai efetuar o update".

Pelo que entendi você quer atualizar os registros da tabela `cp_feedback_trabalho` que `dhEnvio` dela for diferente de nulo e onde o `id_pessoa_que_enviou` da tabela `b` for igual ao `id_pessoa_que_recebeu` da tabela `a` e o `id_pessoa_que_recebeu` da tabela `b` for igual ao `id_pessoa_que_enviou` da tabela `a` e o `id_projeto` da tabela `b` for igual `id_projeto` da tabela `a` e a `dhEnvio` da tabela `b` for diferente de nulo.

Meu Deus que rolo.

Em SQL é mais simples (Hehe):

```sql
UPDATE a
SET a.visivel = 1
FROM cp_feedback_trabalho AS a
INNER JOIN cp_feedback_trabalho AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.dhEnvio IS NOT NULL
  AND b.id_pessoa_que_enviou = a.id_pessoa_que_recebeu
  AND b.id_pessoa_que_recebeu = a.id_pessoa_que_enviou
  AND b.id_projeto = a.id_projeto
  AND b.dhEnvio IS NOT NULL
```

Olhe ai e vê se funciona.